# Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Newcomer (answer) category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Newcomer (answer)](/a/7103) category.

> *Best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2016.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer. Include a short explanation of what makes the suggestions in the answer exceptional.

The following [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/611431/best-of-code-review-best-newcomer-answer-category) will return all potential candidates.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post. Nominated answers must have a creation date in 2016. Downvotes don't count. Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cody Gray's answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151038/9357) on [Implementing realloc in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151019/9357) left a good impression on me.

It started out simple enough, with the usual remarks about formatting, braces, and declarations.  Then it gets more insightful:

- The call to `malloc()` is buggy.
- The call to `memset()` is unnecessary.
- The entire `my_realloc()` function is buggy, and in fact impossible to write without access to the internals of the corresponding `malloc` function.

Then, there is a heavily commented suggested implementation that explains in detail how it works.

The answer concludes with a general discussion about the complexity of `realloc` and suggestions on how to tame that complexity.

In all, it's a very thorough and impressive discussion of just 8 lines of code — and Cody's other answers are equally top-notch.

Answer (score 5):

[Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/123748/71574) on "Event scheduler in C" by [@Herickson](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/101048/herickson).  First answer posted March of 2016.

Of the most upvoted answers, this is the first one that reviewed multiple aspects of the code rather than making a single observation.  It explains how to use a `do`/`while` loop effectively to reduce code length, and it thoroughly covers `malloc` and null pointers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to nominate [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144646/4203) to the question "[Battle game in one 900-line class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144601/4203)".  From an answerer's perspective, this is one of the answers that I put the most effort into.  I came back to the question several times over a period of days.  The answer covered various beginner issues from excessive duplication through to misleading line spacing, eventually resulting in a suggested alternate implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/constructors-for-a-class-to-represent-a-price-in-%E2%82%AC-or/115796#115796) on [Constructors for a class to represent a price in € or $](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/constructors-for-a-class-to-represent-a-price-in-%E2%82%AC-or) by [Philip C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27863/philip-c) posted on January 2016.

This topvoted but unfortunately not accepted answer is made as a step by step guide resulting in an easily extensible, maintainable and readable version of the former code.

The answerer explained well how and why the changes should be made.

Answer (score 1):

[Denis'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98577/denis) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150753/4203) on [Command Tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149212/4203) was exactly what I'm looking for in a good answer.  It offered both a critique on the current implementation *and* suggestions about an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to [C++ Blackjack game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133489/c-blackjack-game/133501#133501) posted by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/4203/forsvarir

It has valid points on:

- Variable scoping
- Domain problem modellini
- Code duplicazione (my personal favourite)
- Bug fixing
- Constant extraction / Naming